# SD card not showing up in fdisk

Tags: mount, format, sd-card

I used this SD-card for 3 months in my Android device.
Now my phone tells me that it's "broken" and needs to be formatted, yet the format fails on the phone.

Ubuntu won't recognize the card at all. (tried `sudo fdisk -l`) Although the Card-Reader works, as it was able to read and write on another card.

Is there any way to format it or even restore some data?

Comment: Maybe the card hardware and internal software are good, maybe not. If 'only' the partition table or the file system is damaged, you can repair it. Otherwise it is probably damaged beyond repair with tools available to normal users (like you and me). See this link and links from it, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297

Answer (score 1):

After inserting the card, run `dmesg` in a terminal, to see if the card was detected at all. I in doubt, try with your working card to see what output to expect.

If you dont see it in `dmesg` output, it is broken. Buy a new one.